# Executing linux aliases from sqlplus

Tags: bash, alias, sqlplus

In sqlplus there is an option to execute standard shell commands, simply by prefixing them with '!'. Example: `SQL>!ps -af` returns expected processes. My question is, is there an option to execute user defined aliases in the same way? So far I tried:

1. In .bash_profile: `alias sample="ps -af"`.
2. In sqlplus `SQL>!sample`. This doesn't work. `/bin/bash: sample: command not found`.

Comment: Similar issue: [Have xargs use alias instead of binary](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/141367)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the [~/.bash_profile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) is only processed for a **l**ogin shell.
2. [Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) are only available in an **i**nteractive bash session.

So, referencing [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash): `!bash -lic sample`